# listAdapter смена картинки в одном элементе по клику и очистка других

Tags: java, android, adapter, gridview

Проблема заключается в том,что View в листе не обновляется и при нажатии на 1 элемент,нажимается и 11 тоже, помогите разобраться.

```
holder.play_pauseAudio.setTag(1);
holder.play_pauseAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(holder.play_pauseAudio.getTag().toString()) == 1) {
            holder.play_pauseAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_action);
            holder.play_pauseAudio.setTag(2);
        } else {
            holder.play_pauseAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_action);
            holder.play_pauseAudio.setTag(1);
        }
    }
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас где-то ошибка.

Comment: К сожалению мне не удаётся пробить вас по `IP`, чтобы подключиться к вашему компьютеру и посмотреть ваш код. Так что где именно ошибка - не знаю. но она точно есть.

Comment: вроде нет ошибок, а как сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на плей допустим,плей менялся на пауз,а все остальные на плей опять?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, забыл про код, добавил,посмотрите ))

Comment: Ну... Надо хранить в адаптере состояние плей/пауз для всех элементов... И в getView по этим значениям ставить нужное изображение... При нажатии менять состояние конкретного элемента в списке, хранящем эти значения в адаптере... И вызвать перерисовку всех элементов адаптера... Для этого есть метод `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: setTag/getTag тут вам совсем не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

1. Надо хранить в адаптере состояние плей/пауз для всех элементов. Например в виде `ArrayList<Boolean> states = new ArrayList<>();`
2. И в getView по этим значениям ставить нужное изображение.
3. При нажатии менять состояние конкретного элемента в списке, хранящем эти значения в адаптере (cм. п1). И вызвать перерисовку всех элементов адаптера... Для этого есть метод `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

---

Ещё проще:

Сохраняйте позицию нажатого элемента и ставьте картинку плей/пауз по позиции, сохранённой в `int` переменной адаптера.

Т.е. в getView проверяйте, что позиция-аргумент совпадает со значением переменной адаптера и ставьте плэй. Иначе - пауз. а в onClick присваивайте значение этой переменной и вызывайте `notifyDataSetChanged()`